# What to do after you've finished coding your site

Tags: wordpress

I've finally finished my wordpress site, which includes the CSS, PHP, JS, and Wordpress coding!

It looks good on surface to me, but since I've learned to code through the web, I'm wondering if there is a service or a freelancer that will review my site. The site I built is for a apartment rental company.

I want to

1. Ensure the site works fine and meets the standards for normal
   sites. (Not sure if I worded this point correctly)
2. That my site is not missing any wordpress files
3. Everything is setup correctly for SEO

I was thinking I should probably look for a freelancer in India or similar to review the code and make needed changes. However, I'm not even sure what exactly I should ask or if I need to ask.

Comment: Here you go: https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Unit_Test also get this: https://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-check/ and this: https://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-bar/. Oh and I forgot: https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Coding_Standards

Answer (score 1):

I recommend some tools:

- [valid your html output, with w3c validator](https://validator.w3.org/)
- https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/ to get some tips for improving your theme

For SEO, [this plugin](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/) is very good, with social graph and clean meta, `robots.txt`.